# Writing in a textbox in a form from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to write the result of my query in a textbox in the main form, from another class. What is the best and easy way to achieve this?

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: I haven't tried anything since I don't know how to do this. I have a form with some textboxes and when someone clicks a button, I want to populate those textboxes with some data from a DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your external class should not know anything about a textbox. It may know about your form in order to send the result there, but the elements are belong to the form and should not be exposed (it is what is called encapsulation).

I suggest you to have a meaningful method on your form, something like ShowListOfUsers(users), or whatever you do, call it appropriately so it can be understood externally.
Then in this method you put the result into the controls (textbox) as you want it.

I also suggest you to have an interface for the form which will contain such behavioral methods and have your window implemented this interface, something like:

```
public interface IOrderView
{
    void ShowOrderDiscount(result);
}
```

so your external class will know only about the interface, not about the window, the textbox, etc.

Now your query component is trivial:

```
public class SomeOperation
{
    private readonly IOrderView _view;
    public SomeOperation(IOrderView view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }

    public void DoSomething(parameters)
    {
        var result = GetMyComplicatedResult();
        _view.ShowResult(result);
    }
}
```

The code above is not ideal (as I don't know what is your scenario), but the idea is there.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use a public property (or a getter) in your class to retrieve the output of the query.